# Why by changing tensor using detach method make backpropagation not always unable to work in pytorch?

Tags: graph, pytorch, tensor, detach

After constructing a graph, when using the `detach` method to change some tensor value, it is expected that an error pops up when computing the back propagation. However, this is not always the case. In the following two blocks of code: the first one raises an error, while the second one does not. Why does this happen?

```
x = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad=True)
y = x + 1
z = y**2
c = y.detach()
c.zero_()
z.backward(retain_graph=True)
print(x.grad) # errors pop up
```

```
x = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad=True)
y1 = x+1
y2 = x**2
z = 3*y1 + 4*y2
c = y2.detach()
c.zero_()
z.backward(retain_graph=True)
print(x.grad) # no errors. The printed value is 27
```

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR;** In the former example `z = y**2`, so `dz/dy = 2*y`, *i.e.* it's a function of `y` and requires its values to be unchanged to properly compute the backpropagation, hence the error message when applying the in-place operation. In the latter `z = 3*y1 + 4*y2`, so `dz/dy2 = 4`, *i.e.* `y2` values are not needed to compute the gradient, as such its values can be modified freely.

---

- In the former example you have the following computation graph:

  ```
  x ---> y = x + 1 ---> z = y**2
          \
           \ ---> c = y.detach().zero_()
  ```

  Corresponding code:

  ```
  x = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad=True)
  y = x + 1
  z = y**2
  c = y.detach()
  c.zero_()
  z.backward() # errors pop up
  ```

  When calling `c = y.detach()` you effectively detach `c` from the computation graph, while `y` remains attached. However, `c` shares the same data as `y`. This means when you call the in-place operation `c.zero_`, you end up affecting `y`. This is not allowed, because the `y` is part of a computation graph, and its values will be needed for a potential backpropagation from variable `z`.

---

- The second scenario corresponds to this layout:

  ```
    /--> y1 = x + 1 \
  x                  ---> z = 3*y1 + 4*y2
    \--> y2 = x**2  /
           \
            \ ---> c = y2.detach().zero_()
  ```

  Corresponding code:

  ```
  x = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad=True)
  y1 = x + 1
  y2 = x**2
  z = 3*y1 + 4*y2
  c = y2.detach()
  c.zero_()
  z.backward()
  print(x.grad) # no errors. The printed value is 27
  ```

  Here again, we have the same setup, you detach then in-place modify `c` and `y` with `zero_`.

---

The only difference is the operation performed on `y` and `y2` (in the 1st and 2nd example respectively).

- **In the former**, you have `z = y**2`, so the derivative is `2*y`, hence the value of `y` is needed to compute the gradient of that operation.
- **In the latter example** though `z(y2) = constant + 4*y2` so the derivative with respect to `y2` is just a constant: `4`, *i.e.* it doesn't require the value of `y2` to compute its derivative. You can check this by, for instance, defining in 2nd example `z` with `z = 3*y1 + 4*y2**2`: it will raise an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation, which is very clear.